# how to deal with error 1064?

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to write a sql query which outputs the identification number of the product(p_id), as well as the quantity sold in the last year(2016) and the dollar amount generated.

following is my code

```
mysql> select id,
    -> sum(quantity) as Quantity_Sold
    -> sum(amt_paid) as Purchase
    -> from transaction
    -> where order_date like '%2016%'
    -> group by p_id;
```

following is the table i am trying to query form

```
select * from transaction;
+------+------+------+------------+---------------+----------+------+----------+
| T_ID | P_ID | ID   | ORDER_DATE | DELIVERY_DATE | QUANTITY | SP   | AMT_PAID |
+------+------+------+------------+---------------+----------+------+----------+
| T1   | P1   | C2   | 2001-01-16 | 2001-02-01    |        2 |  100 |      200 |
| T10  | P11  | C11  | 2001-06-13 | 2001-06-20    |        3 |   25 |       75 |
| T100 | P11  | C11  | 2004-12-06 | 2004-12-11    |        6 |   25 |      150 |
| T101 | P6   | C3   | 2005-01-07 | 2005-01-12    |        1 |   35 |       35 |
| T102 | P3   | C4   | 2005-01-11 | 2005-01-16    |        4 |  120 |      480 |
| T103 | P12  | C5   | 2005-01-26 | 2005-01-31    |        3 |   90 |      270 |
```

it gives the following error
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sum(quantity) as quantity
sum(amt_paid) as purchase
where order_date like '%2016' at line 2

```
enter code here
```

Comment: looks like you are missing a comma after quanity_sold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your a missing a comma.  But, from a logical perspective, you need to get the `group by` and `select` to match:

```
select p_id, sum(quantity) as Quantity_Sold, sum(amt_paid) as Purchase
from transaction
where order_date >= '2016-01-01' and order_date < '2017-01-01' 
group by p_id;
```

Also, using `like` on a date is a really bad idea.  You should use date functions on dates and use `like` for strings.

Comment: Thank you Gordan, it seems the book I was referring to had a printing mistake. And yes, I tried using the WHERE and BETWEEN statement to deal with the dates, but I think the missing comma was causing the error. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Nikhil . . . I speak from experience when I say that getting code right in books is really, really hard.

Comment: yeah! that's right